# Datagridview filtering blank

Tags: vb.net, forms, events, gridview

I don't know if there's something wrong with the code, but every time I enter a value into the text box the datagridview doesn't filter, meaning it just goes blank as if it didn't find anything. can someone help me with the right code for when I insert text into the textbox, the datagridview filters for instance lets say I enter the letter "M" into the textbox, the the DGV display's all the words that start with M

heres my code

```
If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
        frmReportMenu.ProjectBindingSource.Filter = String.Format_
("[Register number] Like '&" & TextBox1.Text) & "&'"
    Else
        frmReportMenu.ProjectBindingSource.Filter = String.Empty
    End If
```

I cannot find anything to properly filter the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your wildcard character is wrong.  Try using a * instead of the &

```
frmReportMenu.ProjectBindingSource.Filter = String.Format_
("[Register number] Like '*" & TextBox1.Text & "*'")
```

Comment: Thanks was the datacharacter